# Should ParameterServerStrategy shard input data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I'm confused as to whether if input data should be sharded when using `ParameterServerStrategy`. Language around distributed training [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras#dataset_sharding) suggests all multi-worker training should shard input data:

> In multi-worker training, dataset sharding is needed to ensure convergence and performance.

Implies that `ParameterServerStrategy` should shard data. However, the `ParameterServerStrategy` [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras#input_data) states:

> Keras Model.fit with parameter server training assumes that each worker receives the same dataset, except when it is shuffled differently. Therefore, by calling Dataset.shuffle, you ensure more even iterations over the data.

Which implies that I shouldn't shard the input data? How does this work?

Comment: Hi @bli00, parameter server strategy distributes the training steps to a cluster that scales up to thousands of workers.

Answer (score 0):

The data should be sharded like this:

```
def dataset_fn(input_context):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, output_types=output_types)
    dataset = dataset.shard(input_context.num_input_pipelines, input_context.input_pipeline_id)
    dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

distributed_dataset = tf.keras.utils.experimental.DatasetCreator(dataset_fn)
```

you don't need to pass the input_context, it is been taken care by the ParameterServerStrategy